# How to check if gRPC duplex stream endpoint is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, .net-6.0, kestrel

I am trying to confirm the endpoint for a duplex stream is valid without the need to send a message. I have figured out a possible solution for unsecured connections. But when trying to use it with a secure connection, I am receiving an exception.

My client code:

```
        var saCerts = CertificateValidation.CreateTrustedRootCollection( certificateAthorities );

        var options = new GrpcChannelOptions();

        if( url.StartsWith( "https" ) )
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            handler.ClientCertificates.Add( new X509Certificate2( /*certificates*/ ) );

            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = CertificateValidation.CreateCustomRootValidator( saCerts );
            options.HttpHandler = handler;
        }

        channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress( url, options );

        //This is how I found to test an unsecure connection
        channel.ConnectAsync();

        var task = channel.WaitForStateChangedAsync( ConnectivityState.Connecting );
        task.Wait();

        if( channel.State == ConnectivityState.TransientFailure )
            throw new Exception( $"Could not connect to URL: {url}." );

        //End connection test

        var client = new MyMessage.MyMessageClient( channel );

        call= client.Stream( null, null, cancellationSource.Token );
```

If I use a secure endpoint, channel.ConnectAsync() will throw an InvalidOperationException, even when valid.

> Channel is configured with an HTTP transport doesn't support client-side load balancing or connectivity state tracking. The underlying HTTP transport must be a SocketsHttpHandler with no SocketsHttpHandler.ConnectCallback configured. The HTTP transport must be configured on the channel using GrpcChannelOptions.HttpHandler.

Connecting to a secure connection works great, if I don't do that check.

My questions are: Is this a good way to test if the endpoint is valid? If not, what is the best way? And how do I get this to work with https? If I have to use a SocketsHttpHandler as the handler, how do I set up the certificate information like I have above?

Assume that sending a message to test is not a way that will work for me (a decision outside of my control).

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if ConnectAsync is the best way to test a connection, but I found the solution to make it work with https. Changing the HttpClientHandler to SocketsHttpHandler works, as the exception suggested. I am open to other suggestions, but I am posting this solution since I couldn't find this anywhere.

```
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
handler.SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
{
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidation.CreateRemoteCertificateValidationCallback( saCerts ),
    ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection()
};

handler.SslOptions.ClientCertificates.Add( new X509Certificate2( /*Certificate*/ ) );

options.HttpHandler = handler;
```